# Issue while removing blank values in Excel data validation list drop down?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to remove the blank values from data validation drop down list. For that i am dynamically filling all the non blank values from source column (e.g.Column1) to another column (e.g. column2) and finally i refer this dynamic column in data validation list. Below is the formula I am using it to remove the blanks and fill the dynamic column:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX([Column1],SMALL((IF(LEN([Column1]),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS([Column1]))))),ROW([@Column1]))),"")
```

The issue here is that top 3 values from column1 are not getting filled into column2. I observed that `ROW([@Column1]` always return me the index of row corresponding to sheet. I need the index of the row corresponding to table not the sheet?

Could anyone please help.I am kind of stuck on how to achieve this?

[image: Excel screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @ sign in [@Column1] means "the current row".

In place of `ROW([@Column1]` try `row(A1)`. That will return the value 1 and when copied down will adjust to 2, 3, 4, etc.

The complete formula is

=IFERROR(INDEX([Column1],SMALL((IF(LEN([Column1]),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS([Column1]))))),ROW(A1))),"")

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-Shift-Enter

Here is a screenshot of the result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. It does solve  my issue. If i am not wrong, here you are using 'ROW(A1)' to get number list starting from 1. Right?

Comment: Correct. If it does solve your issue, please mark it as the answer.